# How to replace silex in a project and adapt it to php8

Tags: symfony, yaml, settings, silex, php-8

I have this in my project php.

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider(realpath(__DIR__ . '/config/settings.yml')));
$app->register(new \Knp\Provider\MigrationServiceProvider(), array(
    'migration.path' => __DIR__.'/../migration',
));
```

I need to update the code to use php8.

All package are abandoned / archived.

I could replace [silex/silex](https://packagist.org/packages/silex/silex) by [spryker/silexphp](https://packagist.org/packages/spryker/silexphp).

I dont know how to replace this package to get settings.yml configutarion.

- DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider

Someone knows how can i do this?

Comment: Have you considered just moving to Symfony?  The odds of all your Silex packages being maintained are pretty low.  Might be time to just move on.

Comment: upgrading to symfony 4 should be your first step, check out this [github post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8678) on it ;)

Comment: @zedling Your link has some useful info in it but upgrading to S4 was recommended because that was what was available in 2017.  No reason not to go directly to the latest Symfony version or at least the latest LTS version.

Comment: @Cerad you are likely right; I recommended s4, because that is from the same time, and probably it has the most resources on how to do it, and going up from a "stock" symfony 4 to LTS is almost trivial if you just follow the official guide